# Actual typealias 'ApplicationContext' has no corresponding expected declaration

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I got this issue when trying to custom context for kotlin multiplatform

```
Actual typealias 'ApplicationContext' has no corresponding expected declaration
The following declaration is incompatible because modality is different:
    public final expect class ApplicationContext
```

androidMain

```
import android.app.Application

actual typealias ApplicationContext = Application
```

commonMain

```
expect class ApplicationContext
```

iosMain

```
import platform.UIKit.UIView

actual typealias ApplicationContext = UIView
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `expect` class structure should match the class you're typealiasing to.

Android's `context` class is an `abstract` class

```
public abstract class Context {}
```

So the modality error comes from there.

You would need the `expect` class to be `abstract` as well to fix that particular error

```
expect abstract class ApplicationContext
```

Making it `abstract` would break modality for `UIView` as it's not `abstract`. So what you're trying to do is not possible in a straightforward manner.

You would need to think about a different strategy for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: context makes me confuse between android and ios in kotlin multiplatform. Could you suggest other solution

Comment: @Anhdevit I don't have a broad solution because a solution depends on what an app or a library requires. Maybe there is no need to have such a context level expect class. You would need to create a new question on SO with exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Anhdevit On top of last comment, context is very UI related. You should aim to use Kotlin Multiplatform for common business logic across all platforms.